# Error in creating subscription: "SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server"

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have 2 servers:

1. Online server: which is a publisher (SQL Server 2008 R2 workgroup edition)
2. Local server: a subscriber(well string trying to make it one) (SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise edition)

I can connect easily to the online server using the local SSMS, but when i try to create a subscription from the local server it gives me the following error:

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, 'kkkkk'. (Replication.Utilities)

kkkkk is the name of the online server.

i searched a lot, just always the answer was related to that the name of one of the servers has been changed. but this is not the case for me.

1. none of the server names has been changed
2. SQL Server Browser and agent are running on both servers
3. as i said before, using SSMS i can connect to the online server easily

Im stuck and not sure what to do, i think its a misleading error message.

Thanks

Comment: When you register the server in SSMS, are you registering it using the actual server name, or are you using an IP address or localhost?

Comment: i register it using an IP address and also i can give it a name, so i give it the original name of the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cheat.
Add to %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file line like
1.2.3.4 publishername

where 1.2.3.4 - remote server's IP and publishername - required name